# Cursor appearance to Hand

Tags: html, css

The anchor tag below works. However, my question is, 'how can the anchor tag force the **cursor to change its appearance not to *Hand*** (like most links do) when hovering over it?'

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doSomethingh('value');">
      <label class="someClass">Click Me</Label>
</a>
```

**Edited**

I want cursor to appear as Hand but it is showing pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by [**CSS cursor property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html).The cursor property specifies the type of cursor to be displayed when pointing on an element.

```
.someClass {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

now consider white box is `someClass` than on mouse over on the `someClass`  cursor will look like below

> [image]

[image: jsFiddle]

---

**Good Read**

[MDN:`cursor` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/cursor)

Comment: NullPointer -- please do not just edit all the answers adding the same link. add a comment...

Comment: I know this is well off topic, but that's some classy behaviour there NullPointer. You gave me grief for accidentally duplicating an answer after others had supplied it, edited everyone else's answers to add demos and links. Then provided your own answer well after the fact and deleted your comments to me about duplicating answers (including my reply).

Answer (score 2):

Add `cursor:pointer` to label

```
label {cursor:pointer }​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5YHX7/572/)**

Answer (score 2):

in your `.someClass` CSS rules, add:

```
cursor:pointer;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.someClass {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Not going to say anything about the rollback - that was probably OK for you to do, but you could at least explain your answer in your own words...

Comment: Both question and my answer are clear for me: he wants hand as a cursor, I gave him proper CSS. What's wrong with that?

Comment: What is wrong with this is the difference between "give a man a fish" and "teach a man to fish." This may solve the OP's immediate problem, but it doesn't give any help as far as solving future problems himself.

Comment: Adding content make it more likely to help future visitors. It's also a good way to differentiate your answer on easy questions which makes it more likely to get upvotes if you care about that sort of thing